# Replace multiple lines of "!" with one "!"

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I'm using sed to clean up "show tech" or "configs" from Cisco switches.  Sometimes when reviewing the config section there are multiple lines with "!" marks.  I do not want to remove all of ! as this would change the config, but I don't need large groups with just lines of ! marks.

So in short, instead of having:

```
!interface vlan200
!description 
!
!
!
interface vlan201
```

I'd like to clean up up to be:

```
!interface vlan200
!description
!
interface vlan201
```

I realize I can replace/remove the ! using

```
sed 's/^!//g'
```

This removes the ! from the beginning of each line though.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^!$/ and $previous; $previous = /^!$/' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- the variable `$previous` is set to true if the current line contains a single `!`, its value is used when processing the next line to decide whether to print it or not.

Comment: Thanks, I like perl too but haven't used it enough.  Just starting to play around with some bash shell scripting again after many years... thanks, this works!

Answer (score 3):

Another tweak from the [pattern link](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) listed by [gregory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057509/gregory) -

```
sed '/^!$/N; /^!\n!$/!P; D'
```

This from the base pattern of

```
 sed '$!N; /^\(!\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

as mod'ed from

```
 # delete duplicate, consecutive lines from a file (emulates "uniq").
 # First line in a set of duplicate lines is kept, rest are deleted.
 sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

---

### Explained

- guys, check me on this.
  Using [GNU's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to reference, as it's nice, and nothing here seems to conflict with other versions.

> N
>
> Add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space. If there is no more input then sed exits without processing any more commands.

and

> Appending the ! character to the end of an address specification (before the command letter) negates the sense of the match. That is, if the ! character follows an address or an address range, then only lines which do not match the addresses will be selected.

$ is the end of the file, so `$!N` means on lines that are NOT the last line at the end of the file, "Add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space." That makes the pattern space "this line and the next line".

> P
>
> Print out the portion of the pattern space up to the first newline.

So, `/^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P;` means copy the first line from beginning to newline and use it as a \1 backref as part of the pattern, meaning match 2 identical consecutive lines. When those to NOT match (the `/!`), print the first line. It won't print if they *do* match.

> D
>
> If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as if the d command was issued. Otherwise, delete text in the pattern space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.

That `D` at the end of the pattern is shifting off the first line but leaving the second one that was appended into the pattern space.

So literally, it's walking through the file, comparing consecutive lines, and only printing them if they aren't identical.

A *slightly* simpler version (as in, maybe a little easier to read, though it's still doing almost as much work) would be

```
 sed '$!N; /^!\n!$/!P; D'
```

This hardcodes the ball-bat pattern and at least doesn't store and use the backreference, though it's still shifting its way through all the lines. We can reduce that work some by *only stacking* the lines when we see a lone ball-bat:

```
sed '/^!$/N; /^!\n!$/!P; D'
```

The P and D still do their thing. :)

So we're back to the pattern I posted at the top.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
last_line=''
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line = '!' && $last_line = '!' ]] && continue
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
  last_line=$line
done
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/eu7UHm, with output:

```
!interface vlan200
!description 
!
interface vlan201
```

Comment: I appreciate your timely response.  I am just starting to play around with scripting again and while this may work, having a single line solution to implement this is helpful.   Also, I couldn't figure out how to apply this to the file I wanted to manipulate. I'm sure that is my own fault though!

Comment: re: applying this -- `./scriptname <infile >outfile` will do. Or you can put those redirections directly after (on the same line as) the `done`.

Answer (score 1):

with sed, as OP requested:

```
sed -nr 'p;:loop;$!N;s/^(\!)\n\1$/\1/;tloop;D'
```

Note: this is minor tweak (matching only an exclamation point) of one of the common one-liners for sed, found here: http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

Comment: Thank you for continuing to implement the use of sed.... however, the perl solution does appear to work for this issue.  Thanks for the sed link, I'm sure that will be helpful in the future!

Answer (score 1):

sed is for doing s/old/new, **that is all**.

```
$ awk '$0!=p || $0!="!"; {p=$0}' file
!interface vlan200
!description
!
interface vlan201
```

The above will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box. It just says if the current line is different from the last line or the current line isn't a `!` then print it. Then it saves the current line to be tested against the next line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/^!\n!$/!P;D' file
```

Open a window of two lines and if the first and second begin and end with a `!` delete (do not print) the first.